# Quick Sort Python Program

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures, quicksort

I'm trying to figure out why my program isn't fully sorting the arr, here's the code below, output: [7, 9, 6, 1, 5, 10, 15, 7, 2]. Maybe my partition function is wrong.

```py
def quickSort(arr, lower_bound, upper_bound):

    if lower_bound >= upper_bound:
        return

    if lower_bound < upper_bound:
        loc = partition(arr, lower_bound, upper_bound)
        quickSort(arr, lower_bound, loc-1)
        quickSort(arr, loc+1, upper_bound)

def partition(arr, lower_bound, upper_bound):
    pivot = arr[lower_bound]
    start = lower_bound
    end = upper_bound

    while start < end:
        while start <= end and arr[start] <= pivot:
            start += 1
        while start <= end and arr[end] >= pivot:
            end -= 1

        if start < end:
            arr[start], arr[end] = arr[end], arr[start]
        else:
            break

    arr[start], arr[end] = arr[end], arr[start]

    return end

arr = [7, 6, 10, 5, 9, 2, 1, 15, 7]
quickSort(arr, 0, len(arr)-1)

print(arr)
```

Comment: One immediate thing is that in `quickSort` you sort without including `loc`th element (need to adjust one of boundaries to cover this element)

Comment: Please provide the expected [MRE - Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).
Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  We should be able to paste a single block of your code into file, run it, and reproduce your problem.  This also lets us test any suggestions in your context.

Comment: "Maybe my partition function is wrong": why don't you know yet?  We also expect that you will trace the suspect values just before the point of error. Where are you confused about how they got to those values?  Where is your output from testing the partition function?

Comment: The second `arr[start], arr[end] = arr[end], arr[start]` is probably the problem. You're supposed to swap in the pivot, but instead you're swapping stuff in the middle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is in the line *after* the `while` loop:

```
arr[start], arr[end] = arr[end], arr[start]
```

When execution arrives at this statement, `start` and `end` are equal, so this accomplishes nothing. After the `while` loop ends, the pivot value -- which is still sitting at `lower_bound` -- should be moved to where `start` and `end` have met. So correct to:

```
arr[lower_bound], arr[end] = arr[end], pivot
```

And now `return end` is doing what it should do: return the index where the pivot element is sitting, separating the not-greater values (left) from the not-smaller values (right).